# How to get num_rows to work?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here, I am trying to get the number of rows to check to see if a username exists or not.

I am currently getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\oop\ServerSide-Project-Message-Ninja\register.php on line 24
```

Any help is appreciated :)

**register.php**

```
<?php 

require_once("config/config.php");
require_once("classes/database_class.php");
require_once("classes/html_class.php");
require_once("classes/security_class.php");


$objHTML = new makeHTML($register_form_array);

// $objHTML->viewArray();


echo $objHTML->makeHeader('Register for an account on Message Ninja', $keywords="Register, Signup", $description="");


if ($objHTML->checkData()) {
    $data = $objHTML->getFilteredData();

    $db = new database($dsn);
    echo $data['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$data[username]'";
    $res = $db->checkIfRecordExists($sql);
    $row_count = $res->num_rows;

    // if ( $row_count > 0) {
    //  echo "User already exists";
    // } else {
    //  echo "This would normally insert data";
    //  // $sql = "INSERT INTO Members VALUES (NULL,'$data[username]', '$data[password]', 
 //  //          '$data[first_name]', '$data[last_name]', '$data[email]' )";
    //  // if ($db->insert($sql)) {
    //  //  header("location: thankyou.php");
    //  // }
    // }
}


 ?>
<div id="form_wrapper">
<?php



echo $objHTML->openForm();
echo $objHTML->makeRegisterFormRows();
echo $objHTML->makeSubmit('Register');

echo $objHTML->closeForm();

?>
</div>
<?php
echo $objHTML->makeFooter();
?>
```

**database_class.php**

```
<?php   

class database{
    private $objDbConnection;

    function __construct($dsn) {

            $this->objDbConnection = new mysqli($dsn['host'], $dsn['username'],
                                    $dsn['password'], $dsn['database']);

         if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    die("Database connection failed". mysqli_connect_error());
            } 
    }

    function insert($sql) {
         mysqli_query($this->objDbConnection, $sql);

        if(mysqli_errno($this->objDbConnection)) {
            die("Failed query: $sql". $this->objDbConnection->error);
        }
        $intInsertID = $this->objDbConnection->insert_id;
        return $intInsertID;
    }


    function checkIfRecordExists($sql){
        mysqli_query($this->objDbConnection, $sql);

        if(mysqli_errno($this->objDbConnection)) {
            die("Failed query: $sql". $this->objDbConnection->error);
        }
        $intInsertID = $this->objDbConnection;
        return $intInsertID;
    }

 }


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such method in your class .
Even if you had a method num_rows
You should call it on $db object

```
 $db->num_rows($sql) //you will need a query also as a parameter
```

the line

```
   $res = $db->checkIfRecordExists($sql);
```

just returns the objDbConnection object

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I have modified my class and have gotten it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Freelancers WHERE User_Username = '".$username."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
```

Then you need to use another php built in function like that - 
    `$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "peter", "abc123");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test_db",$con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM person";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo mysql_num_rows($result);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query you are missing singe quete `' '` in where clause

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '".$data['username']."''";//in here
```

Comment: still getting: ` Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows`